# Inline CSS show/hide div not working

Tags: php, html, css, image, show-hide

I've got a long(-ish) PHP script in which I have included inline CSS to show and hide text. Here's an example of what I have:

```
<?php
  echo "<div class='ReqAcctAPI'><img src='ajax-loader2.gif'></div>";
  echo "<style type='text/css'>#ReqAcctAPI { display:visible; }</style>";
...
... (processing of other code on page goes here)
...
  echo "<style type='text/css'>#ReqAcctAPI { display:none; }</style>";
  echo "<font color='#00BB00'><b>*** DONE</b></font><br />&nbsp;<br />";
?>
```

It will show the image just fine, but when it reaches the second style tag, it won't hide it.

What have I missed?

Comment: `display:visible;` is not correct value. make it `display:block;` or `display:inline;`

Comment: try using  `display:block;` instead of `display:visible;`

Comment: thanks for your quick reply .. I've changed it to display:block but it still won't hide?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You suppose to add `display:block` or `display:inline-block;` instead of visible. visibility and display are different definitions
Source: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp

Ans:

```
<?php
  echo "<div class='ReqAcctAPI'><img src='ajax-loader2.gif'></div>";
  echo "<style type='text/css'>.ReqAcctAPI { display:block; }</style>";
...
... (processing of other code on page goes here)
...
  echo "<style type='text/css'>.ReqAcctAPI { display:none; }</style>";
  echo "<font color='#00BB00'><b>*** DONE</b></font><br />&nbsp;<br />";
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

In your answer you are using an ID "#" selector to select your element, but your element only has a class.

Class selects are prefixed with a dot e.g. ".ReqAcctAPI"

Note that it is bad practice to put styles inline.

Answer (score 1):

you can use inline css like this (`style='display:block'` for show) or (`style='display:none'` for hide)

```
<?php
  echo "<div class='ReqAcctAPI' style='display:block;'><img src='ajax-loader2.gif'></div>";

...
... (processing of other code on page goes here)
...
echo "<div class='ReqAcctAPI' style='display:none;'><img src='ajax-loader2.gif'></div>";
  echo "<font color='#00BB00'><b>*** DONE</b></font><br />&nbsp;<br />";
?>
```

Comment: thanks for your quick reply .. I've changed it to display:block but it still won't hide?

Comment: you have `class` to your element and you written #ReqAcctAPIselector so go with Class Selector .ReqAcctAPI

Comment: `display:block` will not hide it will show. if you want to hide use `display:none`

Answer (score 0):

You are applying properties in class and defining them in id.

```
 <?php
      echo "<div class='ReqAcctAPI'><img src='ajax-loader2.gif'></div>";
      echo "<style type='text/css'>#ReqAcctAPI { display:visible; }</style>";
```

**Change `class` to `id` in div tag like**:

```
<div id='ReqAcctAPI'><img src='ajax-loader2.gif'></div>
```

**then CSS to:**

```
#ReqAcctAPI { display:block; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
  echo "<div class='ReqAcctAPI' style='display:block'><img src='ajax-loader2.gif'></div>";
...
... (processing of other code on page goes here)
...
  echo "<style type='text/css'>.ReqAcctAPI { display:none; }</style>";
  echo "<font color='#00BB00'><b>*** DONE</b></font><br />&nbsp;<br />";
?>
```

Note: 'ReqAcctAPI' is a class not an id so you need to use '.' and not '#' in your selection.

Answer (score 0):

Yoy have used # instead of . in styles

## #is used for id, for class we used .

change your code

```
<?php
  echo "<div class='ReqAcctAPI'><img src='ajax-loader2.gif'></div>";
  echo "<style type='text/css'>.ReqAcctAPI { display:block; }</style>";
...
... (processing of other code on page goes here)
...
  echo "<style type='text/css'>.ReqAcctAPI { display:none; }</style>";
  echo "<font color='#00BB00'><b>*** DONE</b></font><br />&nbsp;<br />";
?>
```